# В rand генерируются одни и те же числа

Tags: c++

Имеется код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
    int n, k;
    cout << "Enter the size of the first array: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the size of the second array: ";
    cin >> k;

    int* arr_1 = new int[n];
    int* arr_2 = new int[k];


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        srand(time(0));
        arr_1[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << arr_1[i]<<" ";
    }


    system("pause");
}
```

Однако каждый раз в rand генерируется одно и то же число (8 8 8 8 (условно)). В чём проблема

Comment: `srand()` из цикла вынесите.

Answer (score 2):

srand надо вызвать один раз перед циклом. А вы вызываете его каждый раз в цикле с аргументом time(0). Эта функция возвращает время в секундах. Пока цикл выполняется, время остается в рамках той же секунды, и вы повторно инициализируете генератор случайных чисел тем же начальным числом. Потому и rand возвращает одно и то же.